# Tracking Position when Scanning Tokens complicates Parser

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am writing a two pass parser where I first scan the text in to tokens (using `Alex`) then parse those tokens (using `Parsec`).  All well and good until I tried to add position information to the tokens so I can write a good error message.

Originally I had:

```
data Token = TAtom | TString String | TInt Integer | TFloat [...]
```

It seems like I can either add a `Position` element to each `Token` constructor or create a new type like `data TokenWithPosition = T Token Position`.

I have started down the latter path, but now I have a problem of either having to create a `TokenWithPosition` with a fake position when I want to describe a token in Parsec, or I have to unwrap the `TokenWithPosition` every time I want to make a comparison.  In short my nice clean grammar is being overrun with code needed to ignore the position information.

So my question: Is there a clean way to track position information without having it complicate the parser in the second pass?  This seems like something that would have a standard solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use functions from `Text.Parsec.Prim` (for instance, `tokenPrim`) to implement your own "primitive parsers".

Those primitive parsers will update Parsec's internal state with the position information and return a pure `Token` without the position.